# Uploading files to SQL Server without using too much memory

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, file-io

I am working with SQL Server 2008 and `FileStream` data types to save large files in the database.

So far everything is working fine but the problem is my upload method looks like this:

```
public static void UploadFileToDatabase(string location)
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

   byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];

   fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
   fs.Close();

   SaveToDatabaseMethod(data)

   data = null;
}
```

Obviously I am saving the files in memory and then uploading them to server which I think is a really bad practice so is there anyway I can at least limit the amount of memory needed for this ?

What is the best practice in my case ?

Comment: Are you experiencing any problems or why do you want to change this? How big are the files? You should look at the `using` keyword

Comment: What does your SaveToDatabaseMethod look like?  Only way to avoid buffering the file in memory is to stream it out to the SaveToDatabaseMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filestream has a WriteByte method

[WriteByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.writebyte.aspx)

[See The Insert Data Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx)

Not sure this is best practice as it keeps memory down but adds steps.  Would need to test it out.  If the entire files does not load need logic to back it out.